# Como fazer transação de paginas

Tags: php, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá estou fazendo um sistema em php e gostaria de saber como posso fazer para que tenha transição entre paginas , tipo tem cadastro,alterar e relatorio , como posso colocar link das paginas na forma input em html .

Esse é meu código abaixo como posso fazer.

```
<section>

            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="thin"></div>
            <p>SISTEMA DE INVENTÁRIO</p> 

            <form  name="register" action="index.php"  method="post">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Setor" name="setor" >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" name="usuario">
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Hd" name="hd" >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Memória" name="memoria">   
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Processador" name="processador" >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Cd/Dvd" name="cd">   
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Placa Mãe" name="placam" >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="HostName" name="host">   
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Monitor/Patrimônio/Marca/Modelo" name="monitor">   
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Nobreak/Patrimônio/Marca/" name="nobreak" >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Placa de Rede" name="placar">  
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Placa de Vídeo" name="placav">                   

                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
                <input type="submit" value="Alterar" >
                <input type="submit" value="Relatório">


            </form>

        </section>
```

e esse é os links do alterar e relatorio  Projetos/relatorios.php http://localhost/Projetos/busca.php

Como poderia fazer ?

Comment: Acho que você está confundindo transação com transição.

Comment: é isso mesmo meu querido , como posso fazer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Você teria de criar um ficheiro `relatorio.php` no mesmo directório do `index.php`
2. Em vez de 
   `<input type="submit" value="Relatório">` faça 
   `<a href="relatorio.php"> Relatório </a>`
3. Faça mesmo para outras páginas.

Espero ter ajudado.